# Unable to browse wcf service hosted on IIS. seems like timed out

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-security

I have `WCF application` created and then `hosted on IIS server (not my local IIS). IIS running on Windows 2012 Server`

I can browse it on server and it shows me service contract page.

```
http://localhost:4567/DummyService/Service1.svc
```

However when i browse it on different machine, it is timing out with message

```
Url = http://{server ip address}:4567/DummyService/Service1.svc
```

> The site can not be reached.

Not sure why?

Here is my web.config on server

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
 <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />   
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Is firewall TCP port 4567 open on your IIS machine?

Comment: It was problem with port.port was blocked. thanks for pointing it